# How to firstly fetch and then display data in TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I am trying to simply pull data from a joke API, and then display it on the page in the form of plain text.
The problem I get is that sometimes data (the joke) is shown properly and sometimes I get the data but the DOM doesn't change and the result stays "nothing".

It seems that I miss something with propagating the React Element, but I just can't see what I am missing.

Can someone help me solve this?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Joke } from "../App";
import Button from "./Button";

const JokeContainer = () => {
  interface Joke {
    category: string;
    type: string;
    setup: string;
    delivery?: string;
    joke?: string;
  }

  async function fetchJoke() {
    const response = await fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming");
    const json = await response.json();
    setJoke(json);
  }

  const [joke, setJoke] = useState<null | Joke>();

  return (
    <>
      <p>{joke?.setup ?? "nothing"}</p>
      <p>{joke?.delivery}</p>
      <Button onClick={fetchJoke} color="danger">
        My Button
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default JokeContainer;
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Probably request is failing. Did you check dev tools?

Comment: Well, the data is fetched, I can display it on the console each time I press the button ;x

Comment: You can try to put a console.log outside any of this functions to see if the component re-renders after the fetch. Trying it on my machine worked normally, even in playcode.io it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yeah, so I get the double response (it log the data twice) on the console when I put it just below the useState declaration.. I still get the response every time, but only sometimes the response is properly displayed, sometimes I just get "nothing" for like 5,6 clicks and then suddenly 7th click I get the proper data displayed ;x

@Oh yeah sorry, the second log is from react tools so it doesn't matter

Comment: so it should be related to your API response the logic you are using is fine

Comment: if you `console.log(json)` after `const json = await response.json()` is the response is stable there or it's like it is shown in the JSX ?

Comment: Yep, solved, it was the API that was tricking me xD Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes this API returns `twopart` jokes that have `setup` and `delivery` fields and sometimes it returns jokes of type `single` that only have the `joke` field. Since jokes of type `single` have undefined `setup` and `delivery` fields you are seeing `nothing`. [API reference](https://jokeapi.dev/#joke-type).

You can change `<p>{joke?.setup ?? "nothing"}</p>` to `<p>{(joke?.setup || joke?.joke) ?? "nothing"}</p>` to display `single` jokes.

You can also request only `twopart` jokes by adding the `type=twopart` parameter to your API request. [API reference](https://jokeapi.dev/#type-param).

This API also limits clients to 120 requests per minutes, so you might want to add a `try-catch` block surrounding your `fetch` in case that happens. [API reference](https://jokeapi.dev/#rate-limiting).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! :D I can't believe I've spent so much time on this, good to know it wasn't react or TypeScript :x Thanks again! :)